# adding a product in cart in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-10

can someone help me with my code its make sense in my logic but its not really working the start part that makes the new cart field for user is ok but the rest is messy

```
public function add($id)
    {
        $product = Product::with('images')->where('id', $id)->first();
        $items = [
            'product_id' => $product->id,
            'name' => $product->name,
            'image' => $product->images[0]->path,
            'price' => $product->price,
            'quantity' => 1,
        ];
//        dd($items);
        $user = User::where('id', auth()->user()->id)->with('carts')->first();
        if (empty($user->carts)) {
            $user->carts()->create([
                'items' => json_encode($items),
            ]);
            return redirect()->back();
        } else {
            $userItems = json_decode($user->carts->items, true);
            foreach ($userItems as $item) {
                if ($item['product_id'] == $id) {
                    ++$item['quantity'];
                    $userItems = json_encode($userItems);
                    $user->carts->update(['items' => $userItems]);
                    return $user->carts;
                }
            }
            $cart[] = $userItems;
//                dd($);
            $cart[] = $items;
            $user->carts->items = json_encode($cart);
            if ($user->carts->save()) {
                return $user->carts->items;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily refactor your code.

```
public function add($id)
{
    $product = Product::with('images')->find($id);

    if (!$product) {
        return redirect()->back()->with('error', 'Product not found');
    }

    $user = auth()->user();

    // Check if the user has a cart
    if (!$user->carts) {
        // If the user doesn't have a cart, create a new one
        $user->carts()->create([
            'items' => json_encode([[
                'product_id' => $product->id,
                'name' => $product->name,
                'image' => $product->images[0]->path,
                'price' => $product->price,
                'quantity' => 1,
            ]]),
        ]);
    } else {
        $cartItems = json_decode($user->carts->items, true);

        // Check if the product is already in the cart
        $productIndex = array_search($id, array_column($cartItems, 'product_id'));

        if ($productIndex !== false) {
            // Increment the quantity if the product is already in the cart
            $cartItems[$productIndex]['quantity']++;
        } else {
            // Add the product to the cart if it's not already there
            $cartItems[] = [
                'product_id' => $product->id,
                'name' => $product->name,
                'image' => $product->images[0]->path,
                'price' => $product->price,
                'quantity' => 1,
            ];
        }

        $user->carts->items = json_encode($cartItems);
        $user->carts->save();
    }

    return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'Product added to the cart');
}
```